# How to find numbers of employees presently inside building?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an attendance table which stores data like this:

```
emp_id   Action           Time
   1       IN       2019-12-22 09:00:00
   1       OUT      2019-12-22 09:15:00
   2       IN       2019-12-22 09:00:00
   2       OUT      2019-12-22 09:15:00
   2       IN       2019-12-22 09:30:00
```

I want to write a query which gives out put as number of the employees present in the office.

Comment: Alright then, go ahead and write the query.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Welcome Sharad, its best to give it a shot and show us so that you might get little feedback on your attempt and improve

Comment: I think what you mean by "Presently" is comparing the "Time" column to today's day?

Comment: a Present in the office?  Does that mean that there is a secret santa?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the current number and your data is accurate (no duplicate INs and so on), then just use aggregation:

```
select sum(case when action = 'IN' then 1
                when action = 'OUT' then -1
           end)
from attendance;
```

The number of people in the building is the number who have ever entered minus the number who ever left, assuming the building was initially empty.

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.emp_id)
FROM sourcetable s
WHERE s.action = 'IN'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM sourcetable ss
                   WHERE s.emp_id = ss.emp_id
                     AND s.time < ss.time
                     AND ss.action = 'OUT' )
```

If last 'OUT' for some employee is errorneously lost then such employee will be counter as present in.

Comment: I've never seen someone select null from a correleated sub-query for NOT EXISTS -- isn't 1 always used?

Comment: But NULL is not a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT EXISTS and a correlated subquery, but I think using left joins is clear (it is also easier to modify for complex use cases -- eg been in the building for 5 mins.)

First when was the last time someone came in the building

```
 SELECT emp_id, max(time) as time_in
 FROM some_table
 WHERE ACTION = 'IN'
 GROUP BY emp_id
```

Then the last time someone came out

```
 SELECT emp_id, max(time) as time_out
 FROM some_table
 WHERE ACTION = 'OUT'
 GROUP BY emp_id
```

We can get in and out like this

```
 SELECT emp_list.emp_id, time_in, time_out
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT emp_id FROM some_table) as emp_list
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT emp_id, max(time) as time_in
   FROM some_table
   WHERE ACTION = 'IN'
   GROUP BY emp_id
 ) tin on tin.emp_id = emp_list.emp_id
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT emp_id, max(time) as time_out
   FROM some_table
   WHERE ACTION = 'OUT'
   GROUP BY emp_id
 ) tout on tout.emp_id = emp_list.emp_id
```

if out is before in they are in

```
 SELECT emp_list.emp_id, time_in, time_out
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT emp_id FROM some_table) as emp_list
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT emp_id, max(time) as time_in
   FROM some_table
   WHERE ACTION = 'IN'
   GROUP BY emp_id
 ) tin on tin.emp_id = emp_list.emp_id
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT emp_id, max(time) as time_out
   FROM some_table
   WHERE ACTION = 'OUT'
   GROUP BY emp_id
 ) tout on tout.emp_id = emp_list.emp_id
 WHERE COALESCE(time_out,0) < time_in
```

*note how you have a zero value timestamp will depend on your platform.

If you don't know how to do 0 this will work but you can't have in and out be exactly the same in the source data

```
 WHERE COALESCE(time_out,time_in) <= time_in
```

Comment: @Akina -- sure.  I'm doing something a little more advanced here.  I'm showing both how to get information about who went in and who went out but also to join those so you can do analysis on the results.  As long I was writing an answer I figured I should attempt to impart some useful take aways.  I'm aware that I did not directly answer the question in the fewest characters.  If you want that then look to Gordon's answer.

Comment: I used a left join because we are not certain that every employee id has an in record and an out record.  This is a standard pattern.

Comment: left join akina -- `emp_list` has the full list and the subqueries may have a subset.  I want all the values in `emp_list` joined to other queries that have less.  There is no mistake.  This is also why the COALESCE is needed.